# how to add top margin to the download pdf file using JSPDF

Tags: javascript, html, angular, jspdf

[image]
-> In this pdf the content is starting without any top margin, looking for an solution  to add top margin.

-> I tried the below code and i'm looking for a solution to add "top_left_margin= 15" to the downloaded pdf file.but the margin is not getting added.

HTML :-

paragraph 1

paragraph 2

paragraph 3

paragraph 4

paragraph 5

SCRIPT:-

const section: any = document.getElementById('summaryId');

```
var HTML_Width = section.scrollWidth;
        var HTML_Height = section.scrollHeight;
        var top_left_margin = 35;
        var PDF_Width = HTML_Width + (top_left_margin * 2);
        var PDF_Height = (PDF_Width * 1.2) + (top_left_margin * 2);
        var canvas_image_width = HTML_Width;
        var canvas_image_height = HTML_Height;

        var totalPDFPages = Math.ceil(HTML_Height / PDF_Height) - 1;
     
        html2canvas(section, { allowTaint: true }).then(function (canvas) {
          var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
          var imgWidth = 210;
          var pageHeight = 299;
          var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
          var heightLeft = imgHeight;
          var top_left_margin = 15;
          var doc = new jspdf.jsPDF();
          var position = 0;
     
          doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG',top_left_margin, position, imgWidth, imgHeight+30);
          heightLeft -= pageHeight;
    
          while (heightLeft >= 0) {
              position = heightLeft - imgHeight; 
              doc.addPage();
              doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG',top_left_margin,position, imgWidth, imgHeight+30);
              heightLeft -= pageHeight;
          }
        doc.save("Dashboard.pdf");
        });
         
      }
```

Comment: _"but the margin is not getting added."_ - all you did was assign `var top_left_margin = 15;`- and then you are not doing anything anywhere any more with that variable afterwards ... so how could you expect this to have any effect?

Comment: Perhaps you should add that margin directly to the `section` element that you're letting the library draw onto the canvas there?

Comment: @CBroe i have modified that - here is the change doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG',top_left_margin, position, imgWidth, imgHeight+30);. earlier it is  doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG',0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight+30);

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';

export class YourComponent {
  generatePDF() {
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    const topMargin = 20; // You can adjust this value as per your requirement

    // Adding top margin
    doc.setFontSize(10); // Adjust the font size as needed
    doc.text(10, topMargin, ''); // Adjust the coordinates as needed

    // Add your content here
    doc.text(10, topMargin + 10, 'Your content goes here'); // Adjust the coordinates as needed

    // Save the PDF
    doc.save('your_document.pdf');
  }
}
```

May be its helpfull